# Can iPhone 4S' digitizer be fixed?

Tags: iphone, digitizer

My iPhone has broken LCD glass, LCD is working from inside but I think the digitizer is broken.

I have visited many blogs and websites and most of them described to replace all the screen with LCD and digitizer. I want to know if there is a way I can fix the digitizer or do I need to replace the whole package?

Answer (score 1):

The LCD and the digitiser are a single integrated piece and cannot be separated for repair. As Alex said above you would have to replace the entire lot.

This forum post over at iFixit a very popular iPhone/apple/computer repair blog and shop highlights the fact this cannot be done.

http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/25507/Can+I+separate+the+glass+from+the+LCD+screen

Answer (score 0):

You should be glad that your LCD is working fine, else it would be a huge mess for you. You can't fix digitizer, you need to replace it. It's quite simple and you can do that on your own. Here is a blog link that will give you a step by step guideline on how to change your broken and damaged digitizer / Screen.
http://blog.brokenlcds.com/replace-iphone-4s-broken-screen/

When it comes to its worthiness, here is a site that buys smartphone broken LCD screens / digitizers (including iPhone 4, 4s and 5). They will surely offer you some good instant cash for that. Here is the link of that site: http://www.brokenlcds.com/

Comment: Well Thanks for your quick response. But the link that you have given me is the same what I had before, I need to change only digitizer not all 4S screen. Kindly if you have any solution please let me know.